# Why `match` holds references longer than `if` in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime, rust-tokio

Noticed the following difference between `match` and `if` in Rust regarding lifetimes - let's say we have simple struct:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
  is_valid(&self) -> bool { true }
}
```

and a mutex that holds it:

```rust
let foo = tokio::sync::Mutex::new(Foo);
```

With the following `match` the lock exists until the end of the `match` construct:

```rust
match foo.lock().await.is_valid() {
  _ => foo.lock().await.is_valid(), // Deadlock.
};
```

This will not finish as the lock still holds when the second line is trying to acquire it. However using an `if` will release the first lock right after evaluating the bool:

```rust
if foo.lock().await.is_valid() {
  foo.lock().await.is_valid(); // This is fine.
}
```

This code finishes with the lock engaged twice. Does this mean `match` hangs on the references more than `if`? What's the explanation?

Comment: In `match` it will need to hold the value for the purposes of branching, as those values can be used *within* the branch, while the `if` evaluates and moves on. It's likely the `if` value immediately gets dropped, while the `match` one does not until the match is complete.

Comment: @tadman `match foo.lock().await.is_valid()` I assumed only returns an owned (no reference) boolean, which naively thinking should have no connection to where it came from (`foo` or its lock). Can match still reach back to that? Or the bool is not fully copied? Not sure I grasp it still.

Comment: It's likely that the boolean is the product of an intermediate object that is retained until evaluation is complete, which in the case of `match` is inconveniently late. You could always assign to a variable first, then `match` on it, that might deal with the scope. As in `let valid = { foo.lock().await.is_valid() }`.

Comment: I know there is a github issue that explain why, thus find it is hard ^^

Comment: @Stargateur Not sure if [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57017#issuecomment-1178353498) is the one? If not, [amos](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/a-rust-match-made-in-hell#all-together-now) is certainly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37612) will give you the information you're looking for.

In short the Drop trait is triggered after everything in the match statement is resolved. That means that by the time the inner lock is called, the outer one hasn't been freed yet. For the if statement, the Drop trait is called immediately after the condition is checked and before the condition block is called.

Interestingly, this seems to also occur with `if let` expressions too. The following code also deadlocks:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn is_valid(&self) -> bool { true }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = tokio::sync::Mutex::new(Foo);

    if let true = foo.lock().await.is_valid() {
        foo.lock().await.is_valid();
    };
}
```